# Question about reading signal timing diagram

Tags: pic, lcd

I am trying to create a library to interface a graphical LCD using the ILI9341 driver to a PIC uC. My question is about the following timing diagram from the ILI9341 datasheet (follow the link, since I can't post pictures yet).

[image: Timing Diagram]

I am confused about what the data/command line 'D/CX' needs to be. The datasheet implies earlier that is needs to be LOW when a command is sent and HIGH when data is sent, and the diagram is of data being sent. But according to the diagram, the 'D/CX' line is ambiguous until every 8th clock pulse (SCK) where it changes states. The state changes are labeled "1."

What does this mean? Does this mean it doesn't matter what it is as long as it's HIGH on every 8th clock rising edge?